# Python, Reading Zip files of a subdirectory. Windows object is not iterable

Tags: python, pathlib

I am trying to loop through my subdirectories to read in my zip files. I am getting error `TypeError: 'WindowsPath' object is not iterable`

What i am trying:

```
path = Path("O:/Stack/Over/Flow/")
for p in path.rglob("*"):
     print(p.name)
     zip_files = (str(x) for x in Path(p.name).glob("*.zip"))
     df = process_files(p)   #function
```

What does work - when I go to the folder directly with my path:

```
path = r'O:/Stack/Over/Flow/2022 - 10/'
zip_files = (str(x) for x in Path(path).glob("*.zip"))
df = process_files(zip_files)
```

any help would be appreciated.

Directory structure is like:

```
 //Stack/Over/Flow/2022 - 10/Original.zip 
 //Stack/Over/Flow/2022 - 09/Next file.zip
```

function i call:

```
from io import BytesIO
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os
import pandas as pd


def process_files(files: list) -> pd.DataFrame:
    file_mapping = {}
    for file in files:
        #data_mapping = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(ZipFile(file).read(Path(file).stem)), sheet_name=None)
        
        archive = ZipFile(file)

        # find file names in the archive which end in `.xls`, `.xlsx`, `.xlsb`, ...
        files_in_archive = archive.namelist()
        excel_files_in_archive = [
            f for f in files_in_archive if Path(f).suffix[:4] == ".xls"
        ]
        # ensure we only have one file (otherwise, loop or choose one somehow)
        assert len(excel_files_in_archive) == 1

        # read in data
        data_mapping = pd.read_excel(
            BytesIO(archive.read(excel_files_in_archive[0])),
            sheet_name=None,
        )

        row_counts = []
        for sheet in list(data_mapping.keys()):
            row_counts.append(len(data_mapping.get(sheet)))

        file_mapping.update({file: sum(row_counts)})

    frame = pd.DataFrame([file_mapping]).transpose().reset_index()
    frame.columns = ["file_name", "row_counts"]

    return frame
```

**New : what I am trying**

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
    for file in files:
        print(files)
        if file.endswith('.zip'):
            df = process_files(os.path.join(root, file))
            print(df) #function
        else:
            print("nyeh")
```

This is returning files like `Original - All fields - 11012021 - 11302021.zip` but then i get an error `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\\'`

Comment: Not enough information,  always post the complete Traceback. What does the directory structure look like? Why didn't you include the zip pattern in the rglob call?

Comment: You call ` df = process_files(p)` instead of ` df = process_files(zip_files)`...

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution using `os.walk()`:

```
zip_files = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(main_path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.zip'):
            zip_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
df = process_files(zip_files)   #function
```

Comment: hi prakash, just to clarify, I add a line like `main_path = r'O:/Stack/Over/Flow'/`? I am getting `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'O'`

Comment: Can you remove `r` and try again?

Comment: still getting that error :(

Comment: Ok i think it was because I was using a mapped drive, im using absolute path now.  Now getting a new error `NameError: name 'df' is not defined`

Comment: This error happens if you try to use `df` variable where it is not accessible,

Comment: Any idea on how this can be fixed prakash?

Comment: This is pretty simple error, you are trying to use df where it is not reachable, you can include the traceback in the question

Comment: Okay so I am using `print(files)` and it prints some of them then I get an error `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\\'`  , any advice on what to do? will update my code.

Comment: In the `process_files()` you are expecting to get the list of zip file, but while calling you are passing the path of a single file, which might be the cause of error. I have updated the code to get the list instead of path str.